AsyncGenerator instead of AsyncSession in pytest, but why
I have fixtures
from typing import AsyncGenerator, Generator

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def init_session(config: Config) -> None:
init_db(config)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def session(init_session: None) -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
async with get_session() as session:
yield session

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def user_repository(session: AsyncSession) -> UserRepository:
return UserRepository(session)

And I have test
import datetime

import pytest
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

import UserStatus
import UserRepository
import RawUser
from tests.test_utils import random_str
from tests.test_utils.user import convert_user_model_to_raw_user, get_user_by_id

TEST_USER_LOGIN = random_str()
TEST_USER_PASSWORD_HASH = random_str()
TEST_USER_STATUS = UserStatus.ACTIVE
TEST_USER_CREATED_AT = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC)
TEST_USER_UPDATED_AT = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC)

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_user(user_repository: UserRepository, session: AsyncSession) -> None:
    raw_user = RawUser(
        login=TEST_USER_LOGIN,
        password_hash=TEST_USER_PASSWORD_HASH,
        status=TEST_USER_STATUS,
        created_at=TEST_USER_CREATED_AT,
        updated_at=TEST_USER_UPDATED_AT,
    )

    user_id = await user_repository.create_user(raw_user)

    user_model = await get_user_by_id(session, user_id)
    user_from_db = convert_user_model_to_raw_user(user_model)
    assert user_from_db == raw_user

Function create_user
from sqlalchemy import insert
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

import UserModel
import RawUser


class UserRepository:
    def __init__(self, session: AsyncSession) -> None:
        self.session = session

    async def create_user(self, raw_user: RawUser) -> int:
        try:
            result = await self.session.execute(
                insert(UserModel)
                .values(
                    login=raw_user.login,
                    password_hash=raw_user.password_hash,
                    status=raw_user.status,
                    created_at=raw_user.created_at,
                    updated_at=raw_user.updated_at,
                )
                .returning(UserModel.id)
            )

            user_id = result.scalar()

            if user_id is None:
                raise RuntimeError("Failed to retrieve user ID after insertion.")

            await self.session.commit()

            return user_id
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            await self.session.rollback()
            raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to create user: {e}")

For some reason I get AsyncGenerator instead of AsyncSession. I've tried everything that comes to mind, but I don't know how to solve this problem. I would be very grateful for your help.
I tried making fixtures synchronous, but it doesn't work. The only way I got the test to complete was when I used a loop inside it to pull the session out of the generator, but I was told that this option is not suitable.
AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'execute'
